# Computing the shape operator of a circular paraboloid?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, vector-fields, tangent-spaces

For the circular paraboloid $$\Sigma : z=x^2+y^2,$$ I was able to find a Gauss map $N : \Sigma\to S^2$ explicitly as $$N((x, y, z))=\left(-\dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{4z+1}}, -\dfrac{2y}{\sqrt{4z+1}}, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4z+1}}\right).$$

How can I compute the shape operator of $\Sigma$ at some point, say $p=(1, 1, 2)$?

Comment: Go back to basics. Understand why it should be a $2\times 2$ matrix. The linear map *is* symmetric, but the matrix with respect to a general (say not orthogonal of equal length) basis will not be. Your text should explain all this. If not, read some of mine (linked in my profile).

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thank you very much. I am trying to self-study differential geometry. I read your nice book. It has lots of details that I haven't seen before. But I wasn't able to find an explicit calculation of the shape operator there.

Comment: You will find your answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4457230/688539)

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational Not really. Bumblebee is trying to do this without I and II. Bumblebee, you're right that I didn't do many examples of computing the shape operator without I and II because it's harder. First you have to understand that you're mapping the tangent plane of $\Sigma$ at $p$ to itself; second, to have a matrix representation you need a *basis* for that tangent plane. You *must* work with a parametrization $g$ of $\Sigma$ ("in local coordinates") and use the corresponding tangent vectors $g_u,g_v$ as your basis *both in domain and in codomain*.

Comment: Why not? Couldn't they use the equation $\delta n(v)=\nabla_v n=-S(v)$ for calculating it @TedShifrin

Comment: @TedShifrin: Can you look at my answer and help me to complete the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, here is how I'd do it. So first let us find the tangent vectors from the positiosn vectors $R(x,y,z) = (x,y,x^2+y^2)$:

$$ \tau_1= \partial_x R = (1,0,2x)$$

$$ \tau_2= \partial_y R = (0,1,2y)$$

**Now to know a matrix, it's sufficient to know it's action on the basis vectors**. We know that $-\nabla_{\tau_1} n = S(\tau_1)$ and $-\nabla_{\tau_2} n = S_{(\tau_2)}$. Also note that:

$$ \nabla_{v} n = \nabla_{v} (n_x e_x + n_y e_y +n_ze_z) = (\nabla_v n_x)e_x + (\nabla_v n_y) e_y + (\nabla_v n_z) e_z$$

The $\nabla_v$ doesn't effect the basis because the cartesian basis is the same everywhere in space.

Putting everything together, you should have your answer.

Comment: Conceptually, I think, I know what happens. But still, I wasn't able to compute the shape operator. Perhaps linear algebra is not my stronghold. Can you look at my partial answer and help me to complete it?